# My website is mobile optimized yet doesn't scroll on mobile

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, scroll, responsive

This Website [www.croossfitnessgym.in](http://www.crossfitnessgym.in) do not scroll on mobile device. I don't know why? Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

you've added the style `overflow:hidden` to your body in  `style.css` at line : 4
this doesn't allow you to scroll the page. you should change it to `overflow-x: hidden` and it should work fine :)
hope it helps . Good Luck!